# Check Boolean if null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
Boolean valid = null;
if (valid == null) {
    log.info("******");
}
```

I have the expression above, I wanted to check if `Boolean` value is `null` and if it is then execute statement inside if clause, but what happened is that it throws me a `NullPointerException`. What should I do to have my if clause evaluated with that given condition `valid == null`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The first thing you should do is ask yourself why you would ever use a `Boolean` object and assign it null. Other than that your code works. Probably `log` is a null-reference you can't call a method on.

Comment: This code doesn't throw NullPointerException (unless `log` is `null`)

Comment: Probably your "log" object that is not instantiated.

Comment: As it is, it won't throw a nullpointerexception. That would happen though if you unboxed the boolean, or if you tried `if(valid)`

Comment: thanks everyone. I forgot that before the expression "valid == null" I checked it first if its "!valid", hence I got NPE since first expression evaluates if it contains a value which is false.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, your log object contains null reference. You can't invoke any method with null reference. Try this:

```
Boolean valid = null;
if(valid == null) {
     System.out.println("Hello");
}
```